# Почему не работает animate при клике

Tags: jquery, click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Global vars
    var arrayImg = [
    'img/slider/1.jpg',
    'img/slider/2.jpg',
    'img/slider/3.jpg',
    'img/slider/4.jpg',
    'img/slider/5.jpg'];
    var i = 0;
    /***************************/
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.slider').height(windowHeight).css("backgroundImage",'url(' + arrayImg[i] + ')');
    $('.div-button-a').on("click", function(){
        i++;
        $('.slider').animate({opacity: 0},200, function(){
            $(this).css(backgroundImage, 'url('+arrayImg[i]+')');
        });
        $('.slider').animate({opacity : 1},200);
    });
});
```

Comment: лол, код немного индусский )

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).css(backgroundImage, 'url('+arrayImg[i]+')');
```

Заменить на:

```
$(this).css({backgroundImage: 'url('+arrayImg[i]+')'});
```

или на:

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url('+arrayImg[i]+')');
```

Хотя странно, должно было как минимум ошибку выплюнуть же.

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: @Lyutenko, Значит нужно больше информации, так как у меня все работает: https://jsfiddle.net/jbdf1vk3/. Проверь классы, посмотри что в консоль падает.